# Will `readlines()` close the opened file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, will

```
file_name = ''
content_list = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()
```

automatically close the opened file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'd need to use with. Either way, readlines will not close the file.

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    content_list = f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

**No, you should use the Context Manager for it:**

```
file_name = 'abc.txt'
with open(file_name, 'r') as txtFile:
    content_list = txtFile.readlines()
```